# Check if input variables are numbers in an array

Tags: php, arrays, space

The problem is the following in PHP:

How to check if the input variables are numbers in an array if all of them was asked to separate with a " " (space) character within a form?

`is_int` and `is_numeric` don't work here, since it's a string not an array.
The answer might be easy, I'm just struggling with it in these late night hours.

The whole problem:
By using only one input field, read in numbers separated by " "(space), then print them out in ascending order. If there is any other variable besides numbers, print "error".

Comment: explode to an array, then array walk and validate the individual entries

Comment: Might be foreach, is_int/is_numeric on indexes and the whole would be included by an if function.

Comment: Where are the numbers(whether or not they are numbers) coming from?  HTML form fields?  PHP Variables?  SQL?  etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "999 999 999 99";

$arr = explode(" ", $str);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(is_numeric($value)){
       echo 'ok';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Might just replace the spaces:

```
if(is_numeric(str_replace(' ', '', $input)) {
    // $input without spaces is numeric
}
```